# Help setting up differential equation from word problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working from the book An Introduction to Differential Equations and their applications by Farlow and so far we have done first order linear equations and separable equations. Now we are starting some applications using these methods. I am stuck on one particular exercise (#15 on page 56) with trying to figure out how to set up the equation. The problem is

The half-life of this new element is 0.15 second, and it was produced at a rate of $2 \times 10^{-5}$ micrograms per second. Assuming that none was present initially, how much is present after $t$ seconds?

Now we have done a few problems that involved exponential decay and how much of some material is left after a certain amount of time given some initial amount, but with this problem I am not sure how to incorporate the fact that there is a constant amount of material being produced in addition to the exponential decay of the material at the same time. I would appreciate any help with how to think about setting up this problem.

Comment: This looks like an exponential decay model with harvesting. In the *absence* of the constant rate of production, the differential equation is $$\frac{dP}{dt}=-\frac{\ln(2)}{0.15}P$$ But since the production rate is $2\times 10^{-5}$, the DE for your model should be $$\frac{dP}{dt}=-\frac{\ln(2)}{0.15}P+2\cdot 10^{-5}$$ Here $P(t)$ is the mass of the element (in micrograms) after $t$ seconds.

Comment: With all such problems, write down what $\Delta P$ is in time $\Delta t$ (approximately).

Answer (score 1):

Based on an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924729/radioactive-decay-with-additive-rate?rq=1) to a similar question I was able to figure out the set up.

The differential equation to describe the change of material over time is

$$ \frac{dQ(t)}{dt} = -kQ(t) + a$$

where $Q(t)$ is the amount of material at time $t$, $a$ is a constant equal to $2 \times 10^{-5}$ (the addition of new material), and the first term on the left hand side is the decay of the material at a rate proportional to the amount present. This equation can be solved by separation of variables which leads to

$$\int_{0}^{Q(t)} \frac{dQ}{-kQ(t) + a} = \int^t_0 x dx $$
and after integration we have

$$ \frac{1}{k} \left( \ln|a| - \ln|-kQ(t) + a| \right) = t. $$

After some rearranging of the above equation to solve for $Q(t)$ we arrive at

$$ Q(t) = \frac{a}{k}(1 - e^{-tk} ).$$

We are given that the half life is $0.15$ and can then calculate $k$ as

$$k = \frac{\ln(2)}{0.15}. $$

Plugging in the the above value for $k$ and $a = 2 \times 10^{-5}$ we get

$$ Q(t) = \frac{0.15 (2 \times 10^{-5})}{\ln2} (1 - e^{-\frac{\ln2}{0.15}t}),$$

which is the answer given in the back of the book.